# How to place a discount on a certain category of goods?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I have two tables:

```
 categories                                products

CatID | Name                ProdID | CatFK | Model | Price |Name
```

I have some categories of products like Sofas, Tables and so on, and all products have their own category being referenced with Categories table by foreign key CatFK
I'm trying to make a discount on for example Sofas in SELECT query, and I can't do it properly.

```
select c.Name, p.Model, P.Price, p.Code
from categories c, products p
where catfk = catid
and (c.name = 'Sofa' and p.Price = p.Price * 0.8);
```

Finally I need to have a list of products(tables,sofas etc) with 4 columns, but in the column Price all sofas must have 80% of the number of price that I have inserted previously

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `case` expression in the `select` list to get the price after the discount:

```sql
SELECT c.Name, p.Model, p.Code, 
       p.price * CASE name WHEN 'Sofa' THEN 0.8 ELSE 1 END AS price
FROM   categories c, products p
WHERE  catfk = catid
```

**EDIT:**

As a side note, implicit joins are considered outdated, and you should probably use an explicit one:

```sql
SELECT c.Name, p.Model, p.Code, 
       p.price * CASE name WHEN 'Sofa' THEN 0.8 ELSE 1 END AS price
FROM   categories c
JOIN   products p ON catfk = catid
```